# ¿Que significa el =* en el where?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Buenas tardes, quisiera que me apoyaran con esto. Tengo una consulta

```
select ...
FROM
        DBSosst..SRG_SUMMARY_NAVIGATION,
        SALDOS_prueba1 a
    WHERE  
        GROUP_ID      = 4 and
        STRUCTURE_ID  = 1118 and
        SUMTO_POINT_TIER= 1 and
        POINT_NAME    =* substring(cuenta,1,1)
```

Que exactamente significa el =* en esta query. nunca en mi vida habia visto esto. Toy usando sqlserver 2000.

muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desde [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983862/sql-server-operator), encontro una sugerencia a reemplazar eso con "left join"

La respuesta aceptada dice, "*Remove this code immediately and replace with a left join*" o, en espanol, algo asi: "*Eliminar este código inmediatamente y reemplazar con una 'left join'*"

Comment: muchas gracias amigo. saludos

Comment: pero amigo, tener en cuenta que se compara el campo de la primera tabla con la primera posicion del campo de la otra tabla. medio raro ese join.. :/

Comment: No sería un left join sino un right join

Comment: Tal vez, solo repitio desde los otro post.

Comment: Pero no basta con repetir desde otros posts, porque pueden no ser iguales. En esta [página de Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259187(v=sql.80).aspx) (en la sección del where) puedes ver que `=*` se debería reemplazar con right join y no con left join como sugieres en la respuesta

Answer (score 4):

Los operadores `*=` y `=*` son un LEFT OUTER JOIN y un RIGHT OUTER JOIN respectivamente, y **no deberían de ser utilizados porque es una sintaxis anticuada que ya no se usa y que no se recomienda porque podría crear confusión con el operador `A *= B` en SQL transaccional** (donde sería equivalente a hacer `A = A*B`). Puedes leer la [fuente aquí](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213228(v=sql.80).aspx) (en inglés).

En tu caso particular, es un RIGHT OUTER JOIN y sería equivalente a hacer algo como esto (no lo he probado):

```
SELECT ...
FROM
    DBSosst..SRG_SUMMARY_NAVIGATION
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN SALDOS_prueba1 ON POINT_NAME = SUBSTRING(cuenta,1,1)
WHERE  
    GROUP_ID      = 4 and
    STRUCTURE_ID  = 1118 and
    SUMTO_POINT_TIER= 1 and
```